# Нужно чтобы сообщение, отправленное боту, пересылалось мне в Телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Бот должен пересылать сообщение мне, если не находит ответ на заданный вопрос. Для этого использую конструкцию:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="На этот вопрос сейчас я не смогу Вам ответить.")
bot.forward_message(ТО_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Но сообщение приходит в этот же чат с ботом с пометкой "от кого", а мне в ЛС не приходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно например использовать метод `forward_message` следующим образом:

```
import telebot

# Создаем экземпляр бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot('ваш токен')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    # Определяем chat_id получателя
    chat_id = 'ваш чат id'

    # Пересылаем сообщение
    bot.forward_message(chat_id, message.chat.id, message.message_id)

# Запускаем бота
bot.polling()
```

А чтобы узнать СОБСТВЕННЫЙ `chat_id`, отправьте сообщение боту и используйте ссылку:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<ваш токен>/getUpdates
```

и далее заберите из ключа `'chat'`->`'id'` ваш `chat_id`.

Результат выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Использовал `telebot`, так как в контексте я не вижу библиотеку которую вы используете

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если ответ устроил вас, пометьте его как **верное** - `Под стрелочками голосования - символ галочки`